# How to refer to an <a> tag's content remotely and dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of  tags as follows:

```
<div id="locationA">
  <a>APPOEL SHIELDS</a><br>
  <a>APPOEL RINANCE LTD</a><br>
  <a>APPOEL INC</a><br>
  <a>APPOEL INTONER CO LTD</a><br>
  <a>APPOELTON POOPERS INC</a><br>
</div>
```

I wired in remotely an event as follows:

```
$("#locationA a").click(function(e){$("#locationB").val(this.value);});
```

The trouble is that `this.value` is not really referring to the `<a>` tag on which the user is clicks in order to transfer the value of the `<a>` tag.

So, how do I indicate in this jQuery command to insert the value of the selected  tag into locationB when the user clicks on the `<a>` tag of choice?

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchors elements don't have a value property. Use this instead:

```
$("#locationA a").click(function(e){$("#locationB").val(this.innerHTML);});
```

Or

```
$("#locationA a").click(function(e){$("#locationB").val($(this).html());});
```

Or

```
$("#locationA a").click(function(e){$("#locationB").val($(this).text());});
```

Comment: Yes, Indeed you are right!  That works.  I have to figure out which tags have what!  `val` and `html` confuse me all the time...  Many thanx, @bFavaretto!  And my apologies that I cannot vote yet.  I don't have enough reputation, but when I get enough I will give you a vote as well

Comment: It's simple, only form elements (input, select, textarea) have value properties. And don't worry about upvoting my answer; you already accepted it, you don't have to upvote it too.